# Regarding Manipulation in String

Tags: c++, string

I have a string as `"Bla bla *.h *.cpp *.png"` . Now I want to put all the file names in vector. So my vector will have

```
vec[0] = "*.h";
vec[1] = "*.cpp";
vec[2] = "*.png";
```

So below is what I wrote.

```
void FileMgr::parseCmdLineForTextSearch(std::string b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
    {
        std::size_t pos = b.find(" *.");

        std::cout << "pos:" << pos << "\n";
        std::size_t pos_ = b.find(pos, " "); // this line does not
               // work, but I want to somehow get the position where
               // the blank space again started so that I can get the
               // the substring from **pos** to just before that blank space
               //thus giving me the exact end point of *.cpp or *.h  
        std::string str2 = b.substr(pos, pos_);
                                         //^^ this pos_ will help //                     
               //me to get the required substring i.e, *.cpp or *.h
        patternVector.push_back(str); 

    }
}
```

P.S: there might be other better way to implement it. But I somehow want to do it the way I mentioned above. Also I need to make sure that even if I am finding the end point of blank space it should always be after the whole text. I dont want to end up finding the blank space which is present in between the text `bla bla`.Is it possible?

Comment: If you search for something starting at the position where you already found it, it will just give you the same position again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop doesn't make any sense. Your logic is done one time for each character in `b`, but the logic itself doesn't depend on `i`. So whatever it is the body of your loop does will just add the same string `b.length()` times to `patternVector`.

What you want to do instead is take advantage of what you know about `b`: it's a bunch of words, space-separated, some of which start with `"*."`. So let's do it that way:

```
void FileMgr::parseCmdLineForTextSearch(const std::string& b)
//                   don't need a copy  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    std::istringstream iss(b);
    std::string word;
    while (iss >> word) {                  // for each word in b
        if (word.find("*.") == 0) {        // if it starts with *.
            patternVector.push_back(word); // add it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get squiggly at `iss` "which says incomplete type not allowed".

Comment: @tanz Add `#include <sstream>`